# How to build column by column dataframe pandas

Tags: pandas, crosstab

I have a dataframe looking like this example

```
A | B | C
__|___|___
s   s  nan
nan x  x
```

I would like to create a table of intersections between columns like this

```
  | A    | B  | C
__|______|____|______
A | True |True| False
__|______|____|______
B | True |True|True
__|______|____|______
C | False|True|True
__|______|____|______
```

Is there an elegant cycle-free way to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: I meant something just like correlation matrix

Comment: I don't think this is possible because you have two rows of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=['s', np.nan], B=['s', 'x'], C=[np.nan, 'x']))
```

---

**Option 1**
You can use `numpy` broadcasting to evaluate each column by each other column.  Then determine if any of the comparisons are `True`

```
v = df.values

pd.DataFrame(
    (v[:, :, None] == v[:, None]).any(0),
    df.columns, df.columns
)

       A     B      C
A   True  True  False
B   True  True   True
C  False  True   True
```

---

By replacing `any` with `sum` you can get a count of how many intersections.

```
v = df.values

pd.DataFrame(
    (v[:, :, None] == v[:, None]).sum(0),
    df.columns, df.columns
)

   A  B  C
A  1  1  0
B  1  2  1
C  0  1  1
```

---

Or use `np.count_nonzero` instead of `sum`

```
v = df.values

pd.DataFrame(
    np.count_nonzero(v[:, :, None] == v[:, None], 0),
    df.columns, df.columns
)

   A  B  C
A  1  1  0
B  1  2  1
C  0  1  1
```

---

**Option 2**
Fun & Creative way

```
d = pd.get_dummies(df.stack()).unstack(fill_value=0)
d = d.T.dot(d)
d.groupby(level=1).sum().groupby(level=1, axis=1).sum()

   A  B  C
A  1  1  0
B  1  2  1
C  0  1  1
```